# MS Paint command line switches

Tags: command-line, file-conversion

I have been looking for documentation related to interacting with MSPaint from the command line. I have only found references to /p, /pt and /wia, but no guidance as to how to use them and their limitations.

I am trying to send some graphics files to the printer and when I drop the file on my printer driver I get a different print output than if I call paint from the command line. I am using the UDC print driver to convert graphics, and I am using paint to send my graphics file to the printer driver in order for my file to convert.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that `mspaint /p filename` and `mspaint /pt filename` both print straight to the default printer. Not sure what `/wia` does, maybe something to do with Windows Image Acquisition?

Also, as others have pointed out, there are many programs a lot more capable for doing what you want than MSPaint.

Comment: you can also add a printer name argument to the `/pt` option. (so `mspaint /pt <filename> <printername>`

Answer (score 3):

I actually suggest you look into doing this in [Paint.Net](http://getpaint.net/) instead. You will have much more freedom.

Comment: Paint.Net is excellent. Its a .NET app and open source. Also its entirely scriptable, and there are some good tutes online for this.

Comment: Paint.NET documentation all says it's not possible to control via command line, e.g. http://bit.ly/kd0R7Z

Comment: Looks like there is a command line tool named PDNBulkUpdaterCmd.exe that complements Paint.Net to perform command line processing. Here is a link http://pdnbulkupdater.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Usage%20from%20Command%20Line

Comment: Paint.NET is not open source. "You may not modify, adapt, rent, lease, loan, sell, or create derivative works based upon the Software or any part thereof." https://getpaint.net/license.html

Answer (score 3):

I suggest [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) hands down... it's like having Photoshop on the command line!

Comment: I am tied to what i can assume will be on the deployed machine, which is why I am looking at using Paint to send my file to the printer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Imagemagick does not require installation, you can just copy the executables.

Comment: what would he syntax be to send a file c:\foo.bmp to the default printer? I am looking at the doc and it is expansive!

Comment: does this program actually allow you to print images? I don't see any such features...

Answer (score 0):

Use PngOptimizer:
https://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/pngoptimizer-portable
it is freeware, doesn't require installation, and is less than 1MB. Converts nicely from BMP to PNG and many other things.
There is a specific command line version PngOptimizerCL to be downloaded from: http://psydk.org/pngoptimizer

To run in command line, converting from bmp to png:
PngOptimizerCL.exe file.bmp file.png

Answer (score -1):

What OS (specific version) are you using? The newer versions of Windows support printing graphics files without the need for MS Paint or any other graphics program. It's called the "Photo Printing Wizard" in XP, and you can even just right-click on a graphics file and choose "Print" right from Explorer - no other program required (and no command line switches needed either).

If all you are trying to do is send some graphics files to the printer, and you're able to drag & drop them, then this is what I'd recommend using.

Comment: I am running on windwos 2003.

Comment: Windows 2003 has the "Photo Printing Wizard" as well.

Comment: He wanted an answer, not a solution. The answer "Don't do this" is very bad answer for a question like "How can I..." .